# Minimizing variance of market neutral portfolio given factor covariance matrix and stock return predictions

Tags: risk-management, factor-models, longshort, minimum-variance, market-neutral

If I am given a return prediction and factor exposures for say 50 stocks, as well as the factor covariance matrix, what is the process to determine the weightings of the minimum variance portfolio, assuming shorting is possible?

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi: do you have the stock return predictions or the factor return predictions ?  If you want to construct something like a minimum variance portfolio, you'll need the factor return predictions and the covariance matrix of the factor returns so that you can calculate the return vector of the stocks and the covariance matrix of the stocks. The specific implementation details using say a barra risk model will probably be explained in "modern portfolio theory" by rudd and clasing.

Comment: I keep seeing this and just want to say one more thing. If you don't want to use the factor model approach, then you can estimate the  returns and estimate a covariance matrix directly and not use a factor model. But estimating those is the hard part. Factor models make estimation somewhat easier but that requires believing in the factor exposures and the factor returns along with the idiosyncratic risk ( all of which are based on the factor model ).